# Unzipping without doubling the memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management

I have function, which perform an unzipping process. The input is a zip file downloaded from the server (`NSData*` type). The way to unzipping:

1. Temporary store the data on file system. (data -> filePath)
2. Unzip it using a third party unzipping library (Objective-zip) (filePath -> NSDictionary)

This works fine, except one thing: Using ARC the memory duplicates! **The zipData is in the memory simultaneously with the data readed from the disk!** 
In case of large file (e.g bigger than 100 Mb) it results a serious memory issue!

**How can i force ARC to release the zipData after it was written to the disk?** 
Is it possible only if I'm going to separate this function for two different code piece (like the two step described before)?

Here is the code:

```
- (NSDictionary*) zipContentOfData:(NSData*)zipData{
    NSString* tmpPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, 
                                                  NSUserDomainMask,
                                                  YES) lastObject];
    NSString* randomZipFileName = @"tmpzip.zip";
    NSString* filePath = [tmpPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:randomZipFileName];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL res = [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    res = [zipData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];

    //I would like to release zipData here!
    NSDictionary *zipContent= nil;
    @try {
        //try to zip out!
        zipContent = [MCZippingHelper unZipFile:filePath];
    }
    @catch (ZipException *ze) {
        //a zipping error!
        //return nil;
    }
    @finally {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
    }

    return zipContent;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to set it to nil?

Comment: Of course, I tried. But, you know, the ARC will release it only when the code piece is finished inside the generated autorelease pool. And the ARC will generate one autorelease pool to one function scope. As a result the zipData will released only after the function is executed.

Comment: I tried it, but the data comes from out of the scope of the function or the autorelease pool. Or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've handled it using several embedded dispatch_asych on the same thread (so I made it asynchronous with a completionBlock).

```
- (void) zipContentOfData:(NSData*)zipData withCompletion:(void (^)(NSDictionary*, NSError*))completion{
NSString* tmpPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, 
                                              NSUserDomainMask,
                                              YES) lastObject];
NSString* randomZipFileName = @"tmpzip.zip";
NSString* filePath = [tmpPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:randomZipFileName];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL res = [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
res = [zipData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];


//I would like to release zipData here!
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   NSDictionary *zipContent= nil;
   @try {
       //try to zip out!
       zipContent = [MCZippingHelper unZipFile:filePath];
       if(completion)completion(zipContent,nil);
   }
   @catch (ZipException *ze) {
    //handle zipping error on some way!
   }
   @finally {
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
       if(completion) completion(nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:@"zippingException" code:-200 userInfo:nil]);
   }

});
}
```

Good luck for coding!

Comment: Would you be willing to share the code that you solved this with to help others in a similar situation?